# Change DB column type on the fly

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

given a java service which should have ideally no downtime, i want to change a table's columntype from varchar to longtext while keeping the service alive.

the service is using spring --> jpa, hibernate and talks to a mysql db.

the entity has the mapped attribute, lets call it foobar, delcared as String.

so now at the moment it looks like this:

- java entity: `String foobar`
- MySQL column: `varchar(255) foobar`

and i want to do a table modify, so it will be like this:

- java entity: `String foobar`
- MySQL column: `longtext foobar`

**QUESTION**:

If i change the mysql column and keep the java service running, will it still be able to read/write to the column or will it throw an error?

Comment: the best way is to try...

Comment: @Sharon Ben Asher
given the constraints of production/development environments in my case: no.

Comment: how about you try and let us know? the safest (and best) way for such migrations is always to (first) perform it on a local or dev environment. If it works there, and if that environment is close enough to your production environment, go ahead.

Comment: seems easy ehough to recreate the situation in non-production env... anyway, given the constraints you mentioned, what options do you have? are you going to implement the change in prod based on an answer from here?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher if he has constraints on his prod environment making it so he can't update the db, he can't change it anyway.

Comment: i did not say i cant update the db, i said that trying that on my environment is not the best option. original statement was: "the best way is to try", and my answer was: "no, it is not the best way."
i just hoped that maybe someone would know a definitive answer how jpa/hibernate/jdbc handles this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory I would say "Yes", the change should be transparent. After all both types are represented in JDBC by the same `java.sql.Types.VARCHAR` type.

However -- that's theory -- and since your application seems to be quite critical I would not blindly trust that theory.

A simple test in the DEV or TEST environment will give you the answer.

Just make sure you use the **EXACT same**:

- Database version,
- JPA version,
- Hibernate version,
- JVM version,
- Application version,
- Libraries,
- etc.